# Deserialization using Newtonsoft.Json - Assigning Default Values to Nulls Parameters

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

My classes are defined below

```
public class HotelRoomResponse
{
    public string rateCode { get; set; }
    public string rateDescription { get; set; }
    public RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
    public string supplierType { get; set; }
    public int propertyId { get; set; }
    public BedTypes BedTypes { get; set; }
    public string smokingPreferences { get; set; }
    public int rateOccupancyPerRoom { get; set; }
    public int quotedOccupancy { get; set; }
    public int minGuestAge { get; set; }
    public RateInfos RateInfos { get; set; }
    public ValueAdds ValueAdds { get; set; }
    public string deepLink { get; set; }
    public RoomImages RoomImages  { get; set; }
} 


public class ValueAdd
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ValueAdds
{
    private string valueaddsize="0";
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "size")]
    [DefaultValue("0")]
    public string size
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueaddsize)
                       ? valueaddsize
                       : ((DefaultValueAttribute)
                          (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["size"].Attributes[
                              typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)])).Value.ToString();
        }
        set { valueaddsize = value; }
    }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<ValueAdd>))]
    public List<ValueAdd> ValueAdd { get; set; } 
}


public class RoomImage
{
    //// private string useurl = "~/no-picture-available.jpg";
    // [DefaultValue("~/no-picture-available.jpg")]
    // public string url { get; set; }

    private string useurl="~/no-picture-available.jpg";
    [DefaultValue("~/no-picture-available.jpg")]
    public string url
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(useurl)
                       ? useurl
                       : ((DefaultValueAttribute)
                          (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["url"].Attributes[
                              typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)])).Value.ToString();
        }
        set { useurl = value; }
    }
}

public class RoomImages
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public RoomImage RoomImage { get; set; }
}
```

While in deserialization process a few parameters are missing i.e each time a few hotels will produce `RoomImages` and `ValueAdds` and a few hotel will not .

My Question is instead of sending Nulls after deserialization process, I am try to set default values but those values are not reflected after deserialization. How can I set default values to `RoomImages` values as "No images url" and `ValueAdds` as "No value adds "?

Answer (score 2):

Json.Net will ignore the properties which do not exist in the json, but I think you talk about the case-2 (below). Then using `NullValueHandling` enum would be enough.

```
//Case 1 (Json doesn't contain the property)
var image = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoomImage>("{}");
Console.WriteLine(image.Url); //<-- ~/no-picture-available.jpg

//Case 2 (Property is explicitly set to null)
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
image = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoomImage>("{\"Url\":null}", settings);
Console.WriteLine(image.Url); //<-- ~/no-picture-available.jpg
```

---

```
public class RoomImage
{
    string _url = "~/no-picture-available.jpg";
    public string Url { get { return _url; } set { _url = value; } }
}
```

Comment: While in DeSerialization process Few parameters values nulls ( public RoomImages RoomImages  { get; set; }) in HotelRoomResponse i.e each time every individual hotels will produce Room Images and Value adds and few hotel will not .

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p Sorry I don't get what you are saying. How about trying above thechnique and see what you get?

Comment: I am DeSerializing HotelRoomResponse class not each individual class

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p What I understand is:  *You want to deserialize a json string and set default values to some properties if corresponding field in json is null*. Am I correct or misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p then above code does exacly this..`RoomImage` class is just an example showing how to set the default value.

Comment: Also worth nothing (nearly 8 years later) that you can also set `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` on the property for targeting individual properties